# How to return true or false for a specific number value in an array?

Tags: javascript

An array has multiple number values and I need to find the one with zero in the middle to return true.

For my output I am getting:

```
false '<-- should be false'
false '<-- should be true'
```

and can't figure out why true won't return true.

I have also tried

```
if (numbers === 1 && numbers  === 2 && numbers  === 3) {
    doesArrayContainZero = false;
} else if (numbers === 1 && numbers  === 0 && numbers  === 2) {
    doesArrayContainZero = true;
}
```

thinking I might need to be more specific for each number but that wasn't it.

Below is the question with my current answer. I can't figure out why it's not correct.

```
function doesArrayContainZero(numbers) {
     if (numbers = [1,2,3]) { return false;} 
     else if (numbers = [1,0,2]) { 
     return true;
     }
}

/* Do not modify code below this line */
console.log(doesArrayContainZero([1, 2, 3]), '<-- should be false');
console.log(doesArrayContainZero([1, 0, 2]), '<-- should be true');
```

Comment: `numbers === 1 && numbers  === 2 && numbers  === 3` doesn't make any sense

Comment: You are supposed to *loop* trough the array and check every individual element for `0`.

Comment: with this line `numbers = [1,2,3]` you are setting `numbers` to be array `[1,2,3]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "includes", or for compatibility with older browsers, "indexOf".

```js
var without0 = [1, 2, 3];
var with0 = [1, 0, 2];

function doesArrayContainZero(numbers) {
   return numbers.indexOf(0) !== -1;
}

console.log(doesArrayContainZero(without0));
console.log(doesArrayContainZero(with0));
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple solution, that using es6 function includes.
https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/Array/includes

```
[1,0,3].includes(0) // true 
[1,1,3].includes(0) // false 

// in your case 
function doesArrayContainZero(numbers) {
   return numbers.includes(0) // returns boolean value
}
```